# What is the sum of $\sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{j}{k+\log j}$ where $k$ is some positive constant?

Tags: functions, summation, logarithms

What is the sum of $\sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{j}{k+\log j}$ where $k$ is some positive constant and $\log$ is the natural log? It would even help to know what the sum of $\sum_{j=2}^{N} \frac{j}{\log j}$ is if there is one. Mathematica has provided little help on this matter, and I am not sure where to start. A strong. upper bound would also be helpful

Comment: For a bound you could use sum / integral comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from
$$  k \leq k+\ln j \leq k + \ln N  \text{,}  $$
we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{N(N+1)}{2k} 
    &= \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{j}{k}  \\
    &\geq \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{j}{k+\ln j}  \\
    &\geq \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{j}{k+\ln N}  \\
    &= \frac{N(N+1)}{2(k + \ln N)}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Those are relatively tight bounds. You don't give any hint about **how** tight you need, so if this isn't tight enough, the Question needs a little expansion.